# nivo slider slow in IE

Tags: jquery, html, drupal, nivo-slider

I am using a nivo slider on a drupal website (http://www.fascinelletremelo.be/test) but the nivo slider is very slow and choppy on transitions in IE.

Doesn anyone know how I can solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of IE are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is just slower at running Javascript than Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc. It's something we just have to live with. You'll find IE9 runs faster.

Consider reducing the number of slices and boxes, depending on the transitions you're using.